# I Started Using Another User On My Mac And Have An Issue With Loading MC Mods

Tags: mac, minecraft

So... I have been using the same user account as another family member and I have started using my own profile. I play Minecraft on my mac a lot and I usually play with mods. But now if I try to play with forge mod loader for fabric... It works fine until I make a new world. Here is the error code:

```
The game crashed whilst mouseclicked event handler
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create save folder
Exit Code: 255
```

And my mac still has what... 100 GB Storage Left. So I Really Don't Know why this would happen.
The Full Report Can Be Found Here:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Don't be sad. I'll do better next time, I promise!

Time: 6/29/21 10:25 PM
Description: mouseClicked event handler

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create save folder
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.screen.CreateWorldScreen.func_146314_g(CreateWorldScreen.java:236) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.screen.CreateWorldScreen.func_231160_c_(CreateWorldScreen.java:214) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.screen.Screen.func_231158_b_(Screen.java:325) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A,re:mixin,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_147108_a(Minecraft.java:852) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A,re:mixin,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.screen.WorldSelectionScreen.func_214326_e(SourceFile:54) ~[?:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.widget.button.Button.func_230930_b_(SourceFile:33) ~[?:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.widget.button.AbstractButton.func_230982_a_(SourceFile:16) ~[?:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.widget.Widget.func_231044_a_(Widget.java:136) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.INestedGuiEventHandler.func_231044_a_(SourceFile:27) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,re:mixin}
    at net.minecraft.client.MouseHelper.func_198033_b(MouseHelper.java:87) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.screen.Screen.func_231153_a_(Screen.java:427) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A,re:mixin,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.MouseHelper.func_198023_a(MouseHelper.java:85) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.MouseHelper.func_228030_c_(MouseHelper.java:175) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.util.concurrent.ThreadTaskExecutor.execute(SourceFile:94) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,re:mixin,pl:accesstransformer:B}
    at net.minecraft.client.MouseHelper.func_228028_b_(MouseHelper.java:174) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWMouseButtonCallbackI.callback(GLFWMouseButtonCallbackI.java:36) ~[lwjgl-glfw-3.2.1.jar:build 12] {}
    at org.lwjgl.system.JNI.invokeV(Native Method) ~[lwjgl-3.2.1.jar:build 12] {}
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwWaitEventsTimeout(GLFW.java:3129) ~[lwjgl-glfw-3.2.1.jar:build 12] {}
    at com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem.limitDisplayFPS(SourceFile:127) ~[?:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_195542_b(Minecraft.java:999) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A,re:mixin,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:607) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A,re:mixin,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:184) ~[1.16.5-forge-36.1.0.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_74] {}
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_74] {}
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_74] {}
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_74] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLClientLaunchProvider.lambda$launchService$0(FMLClientLaunchProvider.java:51) ~[forge-1.16.5-36.1.0.jar:36.1] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.launch(LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.java:37) [modlauncher-8.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:54) [modlauncher-8.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:72) [modlauncher-8.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:82) [modlauncher-8.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:66) [modlauncher-8.0.9.jar:?] {}
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: ~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/saves/World (1)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84) ~[?:1.8.0_74] {}
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[?:1.8.0_74] {}
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107) ~[?:1.8.0_74] {}
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384) ~[?:1.8.0_74] {}
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674) ~[?:1.8.0_74] {}
    at net.minecraft.util.FileUtil.func_214992_a(SourceFile:56) ~[?:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.screen.CreateWorldScreen.func_146314_g(CreateWorldScreen.java:234) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    ... 31 more


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Render thread
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.screen.CreateWorldScreen.func_146314_g(CreateWorldScreen.java:236) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.screen.CreateWorldScreen.func_231160_c_(CreateWorldScreen.java:214) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.screen.Screen.func_231158_b_(Screen.java:325) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A,re:mixin,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_147108_a(Minecraft.java:852) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A,re:mixin,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.screen.WorldSelectionScreen.func_214326_e(SourceFile:54) ~[?:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.widget.button.Button.func_230930_b_(SourceFile:33) ~[?:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.widget.button.AbstractButton.func_230982_a_(SourceFile:16) ~[?:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.widget.Widget.func_231044_a_(Widget.java:136) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.INestedGuiEventHandler.func_231044_a_(SourceFile:27) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,re:mixin}
    at net.minecraft.client.MouseHelper.func_198033_b(MouseHelper.java:87) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
-- Affected screen --
Details:
    Screen name: net.minecraft.client.gui.screen.WorldSelectionScreen
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.screen.Screen.func_231153_a_(Screen.java:427) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A,re:mixin,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.MouseHelper.func_198023_a(MouseHelper.java:85) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.MouseHelper.func_228030_c_(MouseHelper.java:175) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.util.concurrent.ThreadTaskExecutor.execute(SourceFile:94) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,re:mixin,pl:accesstransformer:B}
    at net.minecraft.client.MouseHelper.func_228028_b_(MouseHelper.java:174) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWMouseButtonCallbackI.callback(GLFWMouseButtonCallbackI.java:36) ~[lwjgl-glfw-3.2.1.jar:build 12] {}
    at org.lwjgl.system.JNI.invokeV(Native Method) ~[lwjgl-3.2.1.jar:build 12] {}
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwWaitEventsTimeout(GLFW.java:3129) ~[lwjgl-glfw-3.2.1.jar:build 12] {}
    at com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem.limitDisplayFPS(SourceFile:127) ~[?:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_195542_b(Minecraft.java:999) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A,re:mixin,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:607) ~[?:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A,re:mixin,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:184) ~[1.16.5-forge-36.1.0.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_74] {}
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_74] {}
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_74] {}
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_74] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLClientLaunchProvider.lambda$launchService$0(FMLClientLaunchProvider.java:51) ~[forge-1.16.5-36.1.0.jar:36.1] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.launch(LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.java:37) [modlauncher-8.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:54) [modlauncher-8.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:72) [modlauncher-8.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:82) [modlauncher-8.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:66) [modlauncher-8.0.9.jar:?] {}


-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.16.5
    Minecraft Version ID: 1.16.5
    Operating System: Mac OS X (x86_64) version 10.16
    Java Version: 1.8.0_74, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 1456586656 bytes (1389 MB) / 1979711488 bytes (1888 MB) up to 2147483648 bytes (2048 MB)
    CPUs: 8
    JVM Flags: 8 total; -Xss1M -Xmx2G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
    ModLauncher: 8.0.9+86+master.3cf110c
    ModLauncher launch target: fmlclient
    ModLauncher naming: srg
    ModLauncher services: 
        /mixin-0.8.2.jar mixin PLUGINSERVICE 
        /eventbus-4.0.0.jar eventbus PLUGINSERVICE 
        /forge-1.16.5-36.1.0.jar object_holder_definalize PLUGINSERVICE 
        /forge-1.16.5-36.1.0.jar runtime_enum_extender PLUGINSERVICE 
        /accesstransformers-3.0.1.jar accesstransformer PLUGINSERVICE 
        /forge-1.16.5-36.1.0.jar capability_inject_definalize PLUGINSERVICE 
        /forge-1.16.5-36.1.0.jar runtimedistcleaner PLUGINSERVICE 
        /mixin-0.8.2.jar mixin TRANSFORMATIONSERVICE 
        /forge-1.16.5-36.1.0.jar fml TRANSFORMATIONSERVICE 
    FML: 36.1
    Forge: net.minecraftforge:36.1.0
    FML Language Providers: 
        javafml@36.1
        minecraft@1
    Mod List: 
        forge-1.16.5-36.1.0-client.jar                    |Minecraft                     |minecraft                     |1.16.5              |DONE      |NOSIGNATURE
        Pehkui-2.0.0+1.16.5-forge.jar                     |Pehkui                        |pehkui                        |2.0.0+1.16.5-forge  |DONE      |NOSIGNATURE
        forge-1.16.5-36.1.0-universal.jar                 |Forge                         |forge                         |36.1.0              |DONE      |22:af:21:d8:19:82:7f:93:94:fe:2b:ac:b7:e4:41:57:68:39:87:b1:a7:5c:c6:44:f9:25:74:21:14:f5:0d:90
        hole_filler_mod-1.2.4.2-mc_1.16.x-forge.jar       |Hole Filler Mod               |hole_filler_mod               |1.2.4.2             |DONE      |NOSIGNATURE
    Crash Report UUID: adede6d1-bd1f-45e3-8f70-6614a4e86c2a
    Launched Version: 1.16.5-forge-36.1.0
    Backend library: LWJGL version 3.2.1 build 12
    Backend API: Intel(R) Iris(TM) Plus Graphics OpenGL Engine GL version 2.1 INTEL-16.4.5, Intel Inc.
    GL Caps: Using framebuffer using ARB_framebuffer_object extension
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'forge'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    GPU Warnings: version: 2.1
    Graphics mode: fancy
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: English (US)
    CPU: 8x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1038NG7 CPU @ 2.00GHz
```

Comment: Check your MC Launcher, you might still be trying to save to the other user's folder.

Comment: Actually... I also can't access my old worlds and it says "Locked By Another Running Instance Of Minecraft". So how do I fix this?